# Apache proxy: Proxy based on url

Tags: apache, http, url, mod-rewrite, proxy

I am building a proxy with Apache which proxies everything based on the URL.

My webserver is running locally at: `http://proxy`

When i navigate to `http://proxy/{insert-url-here}` my server proxies `http://proxy/{insert-url-here}` to `{insert-url-here}` , html is loaded correctly, but the resources are not loaded.

The reason for this problem is that the request to all resources initiated from my server are directed using `http://proxy` as the host. I want the requests to use `http://proxy/{insert-url-here}` as the host URL, so the requests can find all the resources.

My current configuration for my VirtualHost in Apache is quite simple:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@company.com
DocumentRoot "C:/proxy/htdocs"
ServerName http://proxy
ServerAlias http://proxy
ErrorLog "logs/error-ssl.log"
CustomLog "logs/access-ssl.log" common

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

<Location />
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all    
</Location>

ProxyPassMatch /(.*) http://$1
ProxyPassReverse /(.*) http://$1
```

**Desired solution:**

I want to proxy `http://proxy/{insert-url-here}` correctly to `{insert-url-here}`. It does not matter if i have to completely change my current configuration.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem. I got a similiar use case and i have tested it in Apache 2.3.
Make sure to disable ProxyPreserveHost so you will not pass the current host. This option can break some dynamic urls.

You can fix the rest of the problems by using a combination of Mod_rewrite and Mod_proxy.
You need to solve this problem in two parts. You need to proxy everything and afterwards fix the links.

`# Fix broken links -> Make sure your requested url is not included
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(www.*.nl)`

`# Clever trick to get the requested url out of the HTTP referer and make it available for the %1 variable
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (www.*.nl)`

`# Rewrite all requests to your proxy with the base url from the RewriteCond above and the captured group from this rule made available by the captured group by Regex
RewriteRule /(.*) http://proxy/%1/$1`

`# Proxy only if the broken links are fixed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.*.nl`

`# This rule makes sure you proxy everything, this will cause broken links which you have to rewrite
RewriteRule /(.*) http://$1 [P]`